# How to setup bootstrap 5 to Blazor Client project

Tags: blazor-webassembly, bootstrap-5

VS templated project of BlazorWebassembly contents the Bootstrap4.
Can anybody to help setup bootstrap 5 to BlazorWebassembly project

Comment: You can see tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9b4hYVNCFK4&ab_channel=KishorTiwari

Answer (score 22):

Copying files into the project is not the proper way.

Instead, use the built-in mechanisms of Visual Studio.

Right-click on the Blazor project > Add > Client-Side Library...

As provider choose 'unpkg' and search for 'bootstrap:
[Client-Side Library Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV15i.png)

After that step, you can see that the Bootstrap libs are added under the target location. Maybe it is good to delete the old Bootstrap version before.

In the index.html you need to include the bootstrap CSS files and/or the bootstrap script files...

```
    <link href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

...

```
    <script src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Pay attention. For the Bootstrap scripts, you also need the latest version of popper.js. You can include it in the same way as Bootstrap or you reference it directly in the index.html

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.6.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-BmM0/BQlqh02wuK5Gz9yrbe7VyIVwOzD1o40yi1IsTjriX/NGF37NyXHfmFzIlMmoSIBXgqDiG1VNU6kB5dBbA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

By the way: In your project, there should be a file named libman.json. In this file, there are all loaded libraries with other version numbers. With a right-click on that file, you can clean or restore your client-side libraries.

Comment: i'm not familiar with the provider. why unpkg?

Comment: i think i get it now. unpkg packages have the same directory strucutre with the "dist" folder, as visual studio templates. so the paths in the HTML or Page, don't have to be changed

Comment: Instead of adding a reference to "popper.js", you can also directly use "bootstrap.bundle.min.js" that already includes it.

Answer (score 8):

Using an out-of-the-box Server or WASM install:

1. Download the Bootstrap 5 files from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/
2. Replace *bootstrap.min.css* and *bootstrap.min.css.map* in *wwwroot/css/bootstrap* with the copies in the zip file in  */bootstrap-5.0.2/dist/css/*

That's it.  As far as I can see there's only one small css change in *Navmenu.razor*

Line 1 replace pl-4 with ps-4 - left is now start [s] right is now end [e].

```
<div class="top-row ps-4 navbar navbar-dark">
```

Note this continues to use the OpenIconic icons as defined in the *site.css*.

Answer (score 3):

There is a free open-source Bootstrap 5 component library for Blazor you might be interested in - HAVIT Blazor:

https://havit.blazor.eu

https://github.com/havit/Havit.Blazor