# Modify button's look

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm looking at the boilerplate code in the Blazor WASM application and I want to figure out how to modify the look of the button on the Counter page.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
```

I see it uses two classes, the "btn" and the "btn-primary" but I have no idea where they are defined as I can't navigate to them by Ctrl-clicking (which is one of the worst thing Microsoft could have done in this new brilliant technology).

So my questions are:

1. Where are those classes defined?
2. What's the easiest way to create my own class defining the look of the button (let's say if I want it to have eg. sharp corners).
3. How can I use my custom predefined color palette in the button?

Comment: They are part of [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/)

Comment: They are imported in the first line of `site.css`

Comment: Note: there often are differences in major versions of Bootstrap (v3.x, v4.x, v5.x etc). So look at thew right docs for your version.

Comment: You can find the origin file of any applied styles through the Browser Dev tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Blazor uses Bootstrap behind the scenes for front-end UI.

And the class "btn" and the "btn-primary" are components of the Bootstrap:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons

To customize the button you can just modify the `btn` class from `app.css` like this:

```
.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b6ec2;
    border-color: #1861ac;
    border-radius: 1px; 
}
```

You might also want want to check the original Bootstrap documentation:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/#sass
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/components/

Comment: Afaik Blazor bootstrap is an optional layer around bootstrap, which is not installed by default.

Comment: I've just double-checked the default template of Blazor WebAssembly project, and see the "bootstrap.min.css" comes there by default.

Comment: yes it does. But like you editted () "Blazor bootstrap" != "Bootstrap"

Comment: So basically, I need to learn Bootstrap before I learn Blazor?

Comment: And how do I use my custom color pallette?

Comment: Yes, @JHBonarius, for the first link I've actually put the first result of bootstrap provided by google, and it was the wrong one and then noticed that that was the wrong one. Fixed right after you've mentioned. Thanks for that :)

Comment: @Val no, you do not "need" to do anything. styling of web pages is done via CSS. Bootstrap provides certain CSS presets. Blazor provides a webpage builder. Blazor therefore also exposes CSS input, thus Bootstrap input. Blazor Bootstrap provides Blazor components representing bootstrap-formatted html components.

Comment: @Val, no need to learn before blazor, you can do it on the way, just make sure you know the basic concepts of Bootstrap like layouting system, how grid works, etc.
To use the custom colors you can either customize the color of the class itself (I've updated answer), or try to re-install the bootstrap along with SASS, so you could use the official solutions of customizing the themes and colors. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/

Comment: Is there a way to have a separate palette file which I could switch (eg. when the user changes from light mode to dark mode) instead of manually editing color values in the main app.css?

Comment: In this case you'll need to fully install the bootstrap to leverage all its functionality. Here's a thread for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68245697/5935112